# Why did I just get a 3 year old review?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

I just did [this low quality post review](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/55460).  However I noticed that this answer has had no activity for about 3 years.

[image: Screencap]

This is rather odd. The post certainly has not been sitting in the queue for the last 3 years, since the queue spends most of its time being empty.

Why did this review show up now?

Comment: It was probably being flagged somehow...

Comment: Some of the reviews are fake ones SE gives you as a test (I believe someone already handled those in the past). I've seen them on SO, but I don't know if it happens on other SE sites too. Or it's just that an auto-flagging system randomly encountered the post.